# Angular material virtual repeat with remote data

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to figure out how the [angular material Virtual Repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) works, the documentation (for me poor noob coder) is not quite clear.
So I've set up a [codepen](http://codepen.io/cmwebcreations/pen/jAzqPm) and added the missing code to connect to a RESTfull server (in this case reddit), but I'm unable to make it works properly. Looking for a good guy who can fix it and explain me a little bit.

Probably there is something incorrect in this method:

```
    DynamicItems.prototype.fetchPage_ = function(pageNumber) {
      // Set the page to null so we know it is already being fetched.
      this.loadedPages[pageNumber] = null;

      // For demo purposes, we simulate loading more items with a timed
      // promise. In real code, this function would likely contain an
      // $http request. (OK HERE IS YOUR $HTTP REQUEST)

        this.loadedPages[pageNumber] = [];
        var pageOffset = pageNumber * this.PAGE_SIZE;              
        var url = "https://api.reddit.com/hot?after=" + this.after + "&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK";        

        $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {

          var items = data.data.children;

            for (var i = pageOffset; i < pageOffset + this.PAGE_SIZE; i++) {
               this.loadedPages[pageNumber].push(items[i].data);
          }
          this.after = "t3_" + items[this.loadedPages[pageNumber].length - 1].data.id;   

        }.bind(this));

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The iteration I used to fill the array was wrong:

```
for(var i = pageOffset; i < pageOffset + this.PAGE_SIZE; i++){
      this.loadedPages[pageNumber].push(items[i].data);
   }
```

the correct code:

```
for (var i in items){
    this.loadedPages[pageNumber].push(items[i].data);
}
```